# listcontourplot on a sector of a circle

Tags: plotting

```
s = Import["Desktop/tension.xlsx"];
ListContourPlot[s, Contours -> 10, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

In fact, it is a contour of a circular part from (2,0) (4,0) to (0,4) (0,2). However, I cannot get a contour on a sector of a circle. It has unnecessary part. How can I delete that red part to make it like the other plot from matlab?

Thanks a lot!!!:)

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the option `RegionFunction`:

```
ss = Table[Sin[i + j^2] + RandomReal[], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}];

ListContourPlot[ss, Contours -> 10, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 20 <= Norm[{x, y}] < 30]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Windy, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.